# azure function app with Runtime version : Error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I created an azure function app, and after deployment, in the portal I got  `Runtime version : Error`
and the application gets `Function Host is not running` exception.

The azure function app is of version: 3.0.13901.0.
At first , I had `"version": "2.0"` in the host.json file, then I updated it to  "version": "3.0.13901.0". But all give me the same exception.

Where should I look to resolve the `Runtime version : Error` issue on azure function app?

Comment: Can this function run successfully locally? Can you give more information about deployment? Or more running logs in the Azure Portal.

Comment: First of all, the highest version in `host.json` is `2.0`, you should not change it to `3.0.13901.0`, for more details, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#version).

`Function Host is not running` usually means that there is some bad configuration in your function app which is causing the host to fail to start up. You can confirm whether the `host.json` or the `proxies.json` is valid.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the function runs successfully in local.  The issue resides in have to register the function app in keyvault!  The function app was not allowed to access keyvault -- that was figured out by looking into the logs from kudu

Comment: could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Sorry, Frank,  you posted as a comment, so not able to accept as answer